# Не делаются скриншоты в pytest

Tags: pytest, allure

Файл conftest.py

```
import os
import allure
import pytest
@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()
    if rep.when == 'call' and rep.failed:
        mode = 'a' if os.path.exists('failures') else 'w'
        try:
            with open('failures', mode) as f:
                if 'request' in item.fixturenames:
                    web_driver = item.funcargs['request']
                else:
                    print('Fail to take screen-shot')
                    return
            allure.attach(
                web_driver.get_screenshot_as_png(),
                name='screenshot',
                attachment_type=allure.attachment_type.PNG
            )
        except Exception as e:
            print('Fail to take screen-shot: {}'.format(e))
def pytest_configure():
    return {'current': None, 'id': None}
```

часть файла с тестами

```
@pytest.fixture()
def check_url():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    current_url = driver.current_url

@pytest.mark.parametrize('id', str(random.randint(11, 999)))
@pytest.fixture(params=["chrome"], scope="class")
def driver_init(request):
    if request.param == "chrome":
        web_driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    request.cls.driver = web_driver
    yield 
    web_driver.close()
```

При создании скриншота выдает ошибку

```
test_create_blog.py::TestsVariablesOnBlogPage::test_variables_on_page_blog_front[chrome] Fail to take screen-shot: 'FixtureRequest' object has no attribute 'get_screenshot_as_png'
RERUN                                                                                                                                    [ 92%]
test_create_blog.py::TestsVariablesOnBlogPage::test_variables_on_page_blog_front[chrome] Fail to take screen-shot: 'FixtureRequest' object has no attribute 'get_screenshot_as_png'
FAILED                                                                                                                                   [ 92%]
test_create_blog.py::TestsVariablesOnBlogPage::test_login_success[chrome] Fail to take screen-shot: 'FixtureRequest' object has no attribute 'get_screenshot_as_png'
```

Подскажите в чем может быть дело.
Тут либо вместо  **request** надо что-то другое (if 'request' in item.fixturenames:)
Либо что-то менять в фикстуре надо.

как я понял нужно инициализировать selenium_webdriver в файле conftest.py, вопрос как именно это сделать

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, ваша ошибка  заключается в том что в строке

```
 web_driver = item.funcargs['request']
```

вы получаете не объект драйвера, который изначально инициализировали, а фактически request
https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html?highlight=api#request

учитывая код вашей fixture, я думаю что вы сможете получить объект драйвера с помощью

```
web_driver = item.funcargs['request'].cls.driver
```